# Can't access application.properties file

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have multiple projects in which I am trying to read application.properties file from one particular project. There's one web application which I am deploying on tomcat. I want to use `application.properties` from another project.

I tried to import appconfig.java from that project to webAppconfig.java.

application.properties file in 1st project `src/main/resources/application.properties` contains `driver=org.postgresql.Driver`

1st project : Appconfig.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Appconfig{

@Value("${driver}")
private String test;
}
```

2nd project : WebAppconfig.java

```
@Import(Appconfig.java)
public class WebAppconfig{

}
```

I was expecting test=org.postgresql.Driver 
but I am getting exception as key "driver" not found.

If I change `application.properties` to something.properties, it works.

I tried following ways:

a)

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
  return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
 }
```

b) tried changing in build path as included, excluded as shown in image

[image]

c)I tried autowiring environment as well.but is didn't work..
I debugged environment variable ..under property sources.it shows`{spring.application.name="project 2 name"}`

Comment: My advice for this is you use a config server who provides configs to clients service.

Comment: Ok..i will try config server..but what is wrong i am doing here..If i rename application.properties file to something.properties,it works as expected..then why not with name application.properties ..is it because it is getting confuse to pick which application.properties file from project 1 or project 2