# How to differentiate path of application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have two projects abc-x and def-y ..
It has application.propeties in src/main/resources folder /
I want to pass path in as 
`@PropertySource("classpath:"application.properties")`
so can we do something like

> `@PropertySource("classpath:"/com/abc-x/src/main/resources/application.properties")`

for project abc-x and

> `@PropertySource("classpath:"/com/def-y/src/main/resources/application.properties")`

for project def-y.

Comment: Have you included the resources in your maven build?

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Comment: Once you have added them to maven, use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.name").getPath()` where `file.name` if the file path **including the extension** relative from the resources folder.

Comment: You don't need this, that is already automatically loaded by Spring Boot. Why make it more complex than that.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54141518/cant-access-application-properties-file]...actually this is my problem

Comment: @M.Deinum ..i had gone through many of your answers on post of application.properties or PropertySource ..or Value..but didn't worked.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry, I did not know.

Comment: Don't do things like that, as that is generally a bad idea. If you want to share global configuration use the environment or a configuration server. Also if both are Spring Boot projects you cannot include one into the other as the jar file is structured differently. Also as stated you are deploying to tomcat, unless the files are globally you cannot access resources cross application (something with security).